# Is "starred by" correct in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, passive-voice, grammaticality-in-context

> The Terminal is starred by Tom Hanks

(Terminal is a movie)

I am trying to state that Tom Hanks is the star in the terminal.

In my context I need to use passive voice. So is **starred by** make sense in this context please?

Answer (score 2):

For starters (no pun intended), verb forms of *to star* include: *(he) starred*, *(he is) starring*, *(he) stars*, *(they) star*.

> The Terminal is star**r**ed by Tom Hanks.

is the correct sentence. It—however—means that Mr. Hanks [*put a starlike symbol next to the movie's title*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/star_2). On the same website you may find the correct usage of the verb with respect to its context. Take note of the “categories” prepended to the definitions (e.g. “**intransitive**”), they provide information on how the word is (commonly) used.

One of the sentences to describe that situation could be:

> *The Terminal* stars Tom Hanks.